# Caching Elastic Search Results in Mysql?

Tags: elasticsearch

I was wondering if it makes sense to cache ElasticSearch search results in a MySQL Database. Of course not everything (e.g. no autocomplete requests) but maybe search queries/results which get requested very very often.

Or is there a better way to cache directly inside ElasticSearch?

Comment: querying mysql would be much heavy as compared to querying elastic.You can create a different index for search results which can store all your recent searches.

Comment: I would never use MySQL as a cache (or any other RDBMS for that matter), there are so many other techs out there that are optimized for caching. Just to cite a few: memcached, redis, etcd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have not specified your exact use case and your queries so its difficult to provide the specific answer but in general its not a good idea to cache the response of ES in MySQL and in my personal experience have not seen anyone doing it.

coming to another part of your question

**is there a better way to cache directly inside ElasticSearch?**

yes, its very much possible and Elasticsearch provides various types of caches like [share-request cache](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/shard-request-cache.html) or [filter cache](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-filter-context.html#filter-context) which is used based on configuration and nature of your query.

You could have a look at [cache blog to get more info](https://sematext.com/blog/elasticsearch-cache-usage/) and ask specific questions if you want to improve the performance of your search queries.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! So, can one say that in general it doesn't make sense to cache ES responses in any other cache system, because ES has its own cache that should be used instead?

Comment: Yes @FrankDrebin, ES has its own caches. Whatever the good folks at Elastic thought would be worth caching, they figured out a way to cache it, and whatever is not cached, well, there probably is a reason why. However, your use case might be different than the general ones, and for you it might makes sense to approach caching differently.

Comment: Okay. And is any ES query cache active out-of-the-box or is this something that must be configured explicitly?

Comment: @FrankDrebin its out of the box and you can have a look at the links in my answer to see how you can fine tune them

Comment: @FrankDrebin pleasure is mine :)